# It can not find module in express, typescript, typeorm

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, typeorm

I was using express + typeorm + typescript.

What i got error is like this

```
CustomError: Cannot find module 'server/src/entity/user.entity' imported server/src/app.ts
```

It can not find module only user.entity.ts
and It can find module another .ts file.

app.ts

```
import { User } from './entity/user.entity';
```

user.entity.ts

```
import { Entity, Column, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from "typeorm"

@Entity()
export class User {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number

    @Column()
    firstName: string

    @Column()
    lastName: string
}
```

tsconfing.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "ESNext",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "target": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "isolatedModules": false,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "inlineSourceMap": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false
  },
  "ts-node": {
      "esm": true
  },
  "lib": ["esnext"]
}
```

[image]

Why it can not find user.entity.ts ...
please help me..!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Probably it is the wrong path to the file.

Comment: I added screenshot, is it wrong?